# RestSharp conectado com Firebase mas não mostra resultado

Tags: c#, rest, firebase

Fiz um serviço em **C#** e agora preciso conectar esse serviço com meu banco no **FireBase**. A seguir encontra-se o método no ***Library*** para conexão com o **FireBase**:

```
public static void restAPI()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://teste.firebaseio.com/");
        var request = new RestRequest("users.json", Method.GET);
        var queryResult = client.Execute<List<Items>>(request).Data;

        Library.WriteErrorLog("RESTAPI: " + queryResult);
    }
```

Função no ***Shceduler*** para inicializar o serviço e chamar o método:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Library.restAPI();
        if (Library.IsConnected())
        {
            Library.WriteErrorLog("////// Com conexão! //////");
            timer1 = new Timer();
            this.timer1.Interval = 3000;
            this.timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
            Library.WriteErrorLog(">> Test Window Service iniciado! <<");
            if (!File.Exists(docBase))
            {
                File.Copy(pricetabLocal, docBase);
                listaBase = Library.MontarListaBase(docBase, ref copiado);
                Library.WriteErrorLog("<< FIM! >>" + copiado);
            }
            else
            {
                Library.WriteErrorLog("Ja existe um arquivo com este nome!");
                listaBase = Library.MontarListaBase(docBase, ref copiado);
                Library.WriteErrorLog("<< FIM! >>" + copiado);
            }
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Library.WriteErrorLog("////// Sem conexão! //////");
        }
    }
```

Classe publica Items:

```
public class Items
    {
        public string usuarios { get; set; }
    }
```

*ACHO* que consegui fazer a conexão porém não consigo visualizar o conteúdo correto, a resposta que retorna é a seguinte:

> RESTAPI: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TestWindowsService.Library+Items]

ps: essa resposta eu escrevo em um bloco de notas.

Essa resposta quer dizer o que?
Se conectei como faço para "garimpar" essa resposta para formata-la?

Answer (score 1):

Essa é a saída padrão pro tipo `List<T>`.

Se você quer especificar o que deve ser escrito no arquivo, faça isso

```
public static void restAPI()
{
    var client = new RestClient("https://segundo-chat.firebaseio.com/");
    var request = new RestRequest("users.json", Method.GET);
    var queryResult = client.Execute<List<Items>>(request).Data;

    foreach(Items item in queryResult)
    {
        Library.WriteErrorLog("Resultado: " + item.usuarios);
    }
}
```

Comment: Fala @jbueno, melhorou meu post dessa vez? rs. Eu editei e coloquei minha classe à qual você faz referência na sua resposta (que falta uma estrutura Items). Eu fiz os ajustes que você disse porém agora fica em branco a resposta.

Comment: Então, jovem. Melhorou bastante, deu pra entender de primeira sua pergunta. A questão é que você envolveu algumas coisas desnecessárias, seu único problema (pelo menos no escopo da publicação) era que não sabia o que estava escrevendo no tal do arquivo. Aliás, vendo este seu "problema" me sinto na obrigação de dizer que está faltando base pra você, me parece que você caiu de para-quedas e está tentando fazer algo com C#. Seria bom dar uma estudada na linguagem antes, ter alguma base de conhecimento. Eu tenho a impressão de que você tá completamente perdido nisso.

Comment: Sobre a solução: tente fazer isso -> `Library.WriteErrorLog("RESTAPI: " + queryResult.Count);` e me diga qual foi o resultado escrito. Aliás, você sabe como debuggar o código?

Comment: A resposta foi: 

RESTAPI: 1

Comment: Bom, isso quer dizer que sua consulta retornou **um** item. Agora, sem mais detalhes, eu não não tenho como te ajudar.

Comment: Ok, obrigado!!!

Answer (score 1):

**< RESPOSTA >**

Para obter o que está no banco de dados **FireBase** no formato **JSON** eu modifiquei apenas meu método:

```
public static void restAPI()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://teste.firebaseio.com/.json");
        var request = new RestRequest("", Method.GET);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        IRestResponse requestget = client.Execute(request);
        Library.WriteErrorLog("RESTAPI: " + requestget.Content);
    }
```